# how to fix this error of importing the tf package in pycharm

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am getting error in importing the package of tensor flow.The error is  ImportError: No module named 'tf.saved_model'; 'tf' is not a package

This is inception model and i need to save this model on my dataset to avoid the training of model again and again

ImportError: No module named 'tf.saved_model'; 'tf' is not a package

Here above is the error occuring while runnning program

Comment: *What command* produces the error???

Comment: did you name your script tensorflow.py or tf.py ?

Comment: i have import the following commands 
import tf.saved_model.builder
import tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder and pycharm give me import error which i have stated above
import tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder.add_meta_graph_and_variables
import tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder.add_meta_graph
import tf.MetaGraphDef

Comment: Because you didn't define the tf. Usually, you should import tensorflow as tf, then you can use the 'tf'.

Comment: i had import tensorflow as tf

Comment: Please *do not* use the comments space to provide code - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
In your case:
    import tensorflow as tf

    export_dir = 'your_dir'

    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)

    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
                sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                signature_def_map={
                    tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
                        prediction_signature
                }
            )
    builder.save()
```